# fetch html content with php

Tags: php, html, fetch, simple-html-dom

I'm trying to fetch data from html document.

```
<table style="border:0px none;margin:0px;padding:0px"><tr><td valign="middle"><p style="background-color:#EE0000;color:#fff;margin-right:5px;padding: 2px 3px;"><b>7767</b></p></td><td valign="middle"><h2 style="padding:1px">title 2</h2></td></tr></table>
```

there are undeterminated number of tables in the page like this one , every time when there are a table I want to get the number after the style, here 7767 , and the sentence in the second , here title 2.
I found some examples I tried to adjust them but it still don't work

```
$html = file_get_html('http://website.com/');


foreach($html->find('table') as $article) {
    $item['nummer']     = $article->find('td.b', 0)->plaintext;
    $item['title']    = $article->find('td.h2', 0)->plaintext;
    $articles[] = $item;
}
```

Comment: `td.b` means a `TD` tag with `class="b"`, and `td.h2` means a `TD` tag with `class="h2"`. Why are you specifying classes in your selectors when your data doesn't have those classes?

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat: [Stay trendy](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182189/please-stop-linking-to-the-zalgo-anti-cthulhu-regex-rant).

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat I fixed that :)

Answer (score 1):

`.` is for specifying classes. If you want to specify that one element is inside another, separate them with a space:

```
$item['nummer']     = $article->find('td b', 0)->plaintext;
$item['title']    = $article->find('td h2', 0)->plaintext;
```

The syntax for the argument to `find` is mostly the same as CSS selectors.

Comment: I thought about mentioning it, but I don't think it's necessary in this case.

Comment: true, just to avoid another question about it ^_^